# C++ convert date formats

Tags: c++, date, format, data-conversion

I would like to convert an `int` date like:

> 20111201

to `string`:

> 01DEC2011

Is there a fast date format conversion built into C++ (or maybe a bash system command I can execute instead) to do this or am I stuck making a switch for all of the months?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the strptime to convert your string to a struct tm, then use strftime to reformat it:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::ostringstream date1;
  date1 << 20111201;

  struct tm tm;
  strptime(date1.str().c_str(), "%Y%m%d", &tm);

  char date2[10];
  strftime(date2, sizeof(date2), "%d%b%Y", &tm);

  std::cout << date1.str() << " -> " << date2 << std::endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
20111201 -> 01Dec2011
```

Just need to convert the Dec to upper case if it's necessary.

Comment: Date is given as int in question, so maybe update the answer with int-string conversion.

Comment: There ya go, doing the conversion from int now.

Comment: `strptime` is not a standard function.

Comment: @JamesKanze `man strptime` claims "Conforming To
SUSv2, POSIX.1-2001", and question specifies running system command with bash as a solution, so...

Comment: @hyde I think he means it's not part of the C++ standard (or C for that matter)

Comment: @Troy yeah (edited my comment above btw), assumed that, but comment implies it is not any kind of standard function at all, and it clearly is.

Comment: @hyde Yes.  It's not part of the C or C++ standard.  I should have stated that more clearly: it is in the Open Systems standard (although despite what the man page says, it _isn't_ Posix, at least not according to the online version of IEEE Std 1003.1-2008, which distinctly documents it as an X/Open extension).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use bash here. The way to go is to use Boost in C++ for more reasons than I've time to list here, but ultimately it will be just as fast as most other solutions you'll encounter and unless your functionality is absolutely time critical, it won't make a great deal of difference anyway.

Also, It's going to be far more flexible and maintainable than all those crappy little hard coded date conversion routines that you always encounter.

The following code will do what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace boost::gregorian;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int dateIn = 20111201;

    // Read the date in from ISO format as an int.
    ostringstream ss;
    ss << dateIn;
    date d(from_undelimited_string( ss.str() ));

    // Set the output format
    date_facet *fct = new date_facet("%d%b%Y");    // [1]
    locale loc = locale(locale::classic(), fct);

    // Render the date as a string;
    ss.str("");
    ss.imbue(loc);
    ss << d;
    string dateOut( ss.str() );
    boost::to_upper( dateOut );

    cout << dateOut << endl;
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
01DEC2011
```

Just changing the format string `"%d%b%Y"` at ref `[1]` will change to a different output format but remember I've converted it to uppercase as well.

Comment: Im delighted to see somebody finally knows how to put together correctly this boost date_time stuff, thx, +1. :) It is still way more complicated than it should be. :(

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing directly built-in, since this format for dates
is relatively rare.  The simplest solution here would be to
break the date up into year month day using `%` and `/`
operators (e.g. month is `value / 100 % 100`), then format the
three values normally, using `std::ostream`, and looking up the
date in a table.  (This would obviously require some error
checking, since not all integral values yield valid dates.)

Answer (score 0):

New answer to old question.  This answer traffics through the C++11/14 `<chrono>` library instead of C's `tm` or `boost::date_time`.  Otherwise it is very similar to the existing answers.  It requires this [free, open-source library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) for the parsing and formatting.

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    auto date1 = 20111201;

    std::stringstream stream;
    stream.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
    stream << date1;

    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
    date::parse(stream, "%Y%m%d", tp);

    auto str = date::format("%d%b%Y", tp);

    auto& ct = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(std::locale::classic());
    ct.toupper(&str.front(), &str.back()+1);
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

I've included `stream.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);` to noisily detect invalid "integer dates".  And I've included old C++98 code to convert the string to uppercase (the `locale` dance at the end).

```
01DEC2011
```

One of the advantages of using a modern C++ date/time library is the ease with which changes can be made.  For example, what if now you need to parse the timestamp not with day-precision, but with millisecond precision?  Here is how that might be done:

```
auto date1 = 20111201093357.275L;

std::stringstream stream;
stream.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
stream << std::fixed << date1;

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
date::parse(stream, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", tp);

auto str = date::format("%d%b%Y %T", tp);

auto& ct = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(std::locale::classic());
ct.toupper(&str.front(), &str.back()+1);
std::cout << str << '\n';
```

which outputs:

```
01DEC2011 09:33:57.275000
```

Or perhaps these timestamps are known to originate from [Chatham Island off the coast of New Zealand](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Chatham+Island/@-44.268442,173.2837716,5z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x72b3e85efc86df7f:0x2c592471336222d4) and you need them in UTC.  Just add one line after the `parse`:

```
tp = date::locate_zone("Pacific/Chatham")->to_sys(tp);
```

And now the output is:

```
30NOV2011 19:48:57.275000
```

Taking into account arbitrary timezones and subsecond precision is currently beyond the capabilities of all other C++ libraries.